# Checking if key is being held down

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've got a game where you place towers on the map, it's working fine they can click and the towers place the the build mode is set to false. I Want to allow the player to hold shift down then they can place multiply towers then when they release shift the build mode will change to false but i can't figure it out.

This is what i've got so far but doesn't seem to work as intended

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_released("ui_accept") and build_mode == true:
        verify_and_build()
    if event.is_action_released("multi_build"):
        cancel_build_mode()
```

I've assigned ui_accept to left click and multi_build to Shift

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get a call to `_input` per input event. And the event object you get as parameter in `_input` represents that single input.

If want to to this with the event object, it would be something like this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("multi_build"):
        build_mode = true
    if event.is_action_released("multi_build"):
        build_mode = false
```

Alternatively, you can use `Input` to check if the action is currently pressed: `Input.is_action_pressed("multi_build")`.